# "unknown-sdk" device when executing tests in Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, spoon, spoon-gradle-plugin

I have a strange situation with Jenkins when trying to run the tests.

The configuration of the job clearly specifies to run the tests on this specific avd: "**hudson_en-US_160_HVGA_android-18_armeabi-v7a**", but for some odd reasons, during the build process, 2 devices are found. One of the devices is the previous one, but the other is called "**unknown-sdk**".

[image]

The tests are successfully executed on the specific avd, and fail on "unknown-sdk":

The relevant portion of the log:

> [SR.runTests] Executing instrumentation suite on 2
>   device(s).
>   [SR.runTests] [emulator-8215] Starting
>   execution.
>   [SR.runTests] [localhost:8216] Starting
>   execution.
>
> Running am instrument -w -r  -e class com.smoke.tests.LoginTest
>   com.muume.dev.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner on
>   unknown-sdk-localhost:8216
>
> 2015-06-17 11:54:05 [SDR.printStream] [localhost:8216] STDOUT 11:54:05
>   I/InstrumentationResultParser: test run failed: 'Unable to find
>   instrumentation info for:
>   ComponentInfo{com.muume.dev.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}

As you can see, it detected 2 devices: **emulator-8215** which is the known avd, and **localhost-8216** which is the unknown and causes the problems.

My question is how to restrict the tests to run only one single emulator, and from where did the "unknown-sdk-localhost" comes from.

Comment: I guess you are using the Android Emulator plugin for Jenkins. Can you paste (part of) the job configuration?

Comment: Maybe look at the running process list on the host and see if you have a hung emulation?

Comment: are u using gennymotion for the other device ? the second device uses adb over http (localhost) and not adb bridge over USB so different ruels apply and i'm not sure spoon knows how to handle that, even android studio and eclipse needs a plugin for gennymotion to function properly and debug or see logs

Comment: i now see it was asked a month ago, Did u get it resolved ?

Comment: then do you use gennymotion ?

Comment: Please post the Jenkins configuration (both the one to start the emulator, if any, and the one about running tests).

Comment: I now see it was asked 5 month ago. Did u get it resolved?

Comment: The reason people have asked about genymotion is that the second emulator is being accessed by IP on the localhost host suggesting it is a virtual machine such as VirtualBox running a genymotion Android instance. The odd thing is that it's port is one higher than the emulator "id" which is a big coincidence... Did the problem go away when you updated the SDK version?

Did you identify the problem and get it fixed? If so could you tell us what happened, even after all this time it looks like 11 people thought this was interesting enough to vote up.

Answer (score 1):

`"unknown-sdk"` is what it tells adb while the emulator is still busy loading itself.